# How to get id of the selected Radio Button in Android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

In my project, I've created 3 Radio Buttons for Multiple Choice options for users. I have some questions and answers in SQLite database which I'm retrieving in `Activity` and then set them in `RadioGroup`. it was working fine upto this but now when I want to get all IDs of selected radio button and then count it. I'm using `'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1'` library ([Reference Link](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper)).

My Activity

```java
public class KlasifikasiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StepperLayout.StepperListener {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(View completeButton) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCompleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(VerificationError verificationError) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onError! -> " + verificationError.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStepSelected(int newStepPosition) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStepSelected! -> " + newStepPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReturn() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

My StepFragment

```java
public class StepFragmentExample extends Fragment implements Step {


    public StepFragmentExample() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
    RadioButton mRadioButton1;
    RadioButton mRadioButton2;
    RadioButton mRadioButton3;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        Log.d("##", "onCreateView: " + bundle.getInt(MyStepperAdapter.CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY)) ;

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_fragment_example, container, false);

        mRadioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupWrapper);

        DatabaseHelper mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        Log.d("#######", String.valueOf(bundle.getInt(MyStepperAdapter.CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY)));
        final List<Klasifikasi> lk = mDBHelper.getListKlasifikasiByGroup(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(bundle.getInt(MyStepperAdapter.CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY)) + 1));
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[lk.size()];
        Log.d("##sz", "onCreateView: " + lk.size()) ;


        int[][] states = new int[][] {
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
        };

        int[] colors = new int[] {
                Color.BLACK,
                Color.BLACK,
                Color.BLACK,
                Color.BLACK
        };

        mRadioButton1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        mRadioButton2 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
        mRadioButton3 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);

        if(lk.size() > 0) {
            Klasifikasi kl0 = lk.get(0);
            Klasifikasi kl1 = lk.get(1);
            Klasifikasi kl2 = lk.get(2);
            mRadioButton1.setText(kl0.getKlasifikasi());
            mRadioButton2.setText(kl1.getKlasifikasi());
            mRadioButton3.setText(kl2.getKlasifikasi());
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public VerificationError verifyStep() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull VerificationError error) {

    }
}
```

How can I get the selected radio button's IDs? My full code is in [this](https://github.com/dmrgalihrahma/Sistem-pakar-metode-belajar) link.

Comment: remove unwanted classes. ask only with specific code. no one have to time analyse entire project code

Answer (score 0):

Use `mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` to get the id of selected `RadioButton` inside `RadioGroup`

Comment: Thankyou, and then how to keep the id? i want to sum each id from radiobutton or maybe make it toast.

Comment: "and then how to keep the id" - Take an `int selectedRB` & store `mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`  in it. "i want to sum each id from radiobutton" can you please elaborate this? You mean you want to add the text shown on those RadioButtons?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "selected Id- "+mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`

Answer (score 0):

You can save those values to SQLite database in new table with question id and answer id and calculate those values in the Final page!!! or you can manage a static Arraylist to store user's Answer. I prefer SQLite to store the values.